# ¿Cómo mostrar dentro de una gráfica en ggplot el ultimo dato de una serie de tiempo?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Necesito mostrar el valor del ultimo dato de mi gráfica en **ggplot** y ese valor multiplicarlo por 100 así aparecerá en porcentaje.

He probado con **geom_text** y no he podido. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
Gra.PIBpb<- data3 %>%
  filter(Año>1990) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, PPIBpb, group = 1)) + geom_line( size = 1.5 , color = "Green") + 
  labs(title="", subtitle = "", y = "Porcentaje") +
  dark_theme_classic() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,0.08,by = 0.005), labels = percent) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size =8), axis.title=element_text(size=13)) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size =15, face = "bold")) + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = x.axis) 
Gra.PIBpb
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de resolverlo (hay varias) es usar un `geom_label()` pero con los datos reducidos a la última fila de tu `data.frame`, algo así:

```
data <- data.frame(Date=1:100, PPIBpb=runif(100))
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=PPIBpb)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.5 , color = "Green") +
  geom_point(data=tail(data,1), size=3,  color = "Green") +
  geom_label(data=tail(data,1), aes(label=round(PPIBpb*100,2)), nudge_x=2, nudge_y =-.05) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios:

- El secreto es `data=tail(data,1)` que solo se limita al último valor
- El `label` es la etiqueta a mostrar y hacemos lo que pides para llegar al porcentaje: `aes(label=round(PPIBpb*100,2))`
- Lo parámetros `nudge_x` y `nudge_y` se  usan para ajustar la posición de la etiqueta
- El `geom_point()` es opcional, pero hace mas claro el sentido de la etiqueta
- En tu caso deberás generar un `data.frame` con los datos filtrados, por ejemplo: `data3 %>% filter(Año>1990) -> data` y luego sí usar `data` para graficar.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda Sr Patricio, acabo de colocar mis dudas en una respuesta, si me podría ayudar por favor. Saludos

Comment: Hola Sebastian, no uses las respuestas para repreguntar, para eso están los comentarios, de cualquier forma, tienes dos problemas, el 1ero es que no hiciste lo que te decía en mi último comentario, debes generar un nuevo `data.frame` con los datos ya filtrados, llámalo si quieres `data4` y sobre este aplicas ggplot, es decir  `data4 %>% ggplot(....` , luego esto `geom_label(data3=tail(data3,1)..` esta mal, por que el nombre del parámetro no es `data3` sino `data`, debiera ser `geom_label(data=tail(data4,1)..` (data4 si hiciste lo anterior)